# Dynamic Time Warping (dtw): why do some Rabiner-Juang step patterns work whilst others don’t

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dtw

I am trying to cluster time series data from a longitudinal survey that includes participants’ yearly reported incomes. These income trajectories vary in length, so dynamic time warping seems like an appropriate tool for calculating a distance matrix.

Some experimenting revealed that how these trajectories are mapped to each other varies significantly depending on the assigned step pattern. I therefore would like to pick the most appropriate one for my dataset. I’m not very experienced with dynamic time warping, so I decided to try clustering on a small sample using distance matrices created by a range of step patterns and see which one had the best performance metrics.

To do this, I used the `dtw` package’s `rabinerJuangStepPattern` function, which can implement a “comprehensive set of step-patterns” as outlined in Rabiner & Juang (1993; I wasn't able to get a copy of this document). I therefore created a nested for loop to iterate through all configurations of the Rabiner-Juang set, and found that many of them threw the following error:

```
Error in dtw(… :  No warping path exists that is allowed by costraints
```

I’ve replicated this problem using a toy version of my data, which only tries to calculate distances relative to the first participant in the dataset:

```
# Import required libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(dtw)

# Set seed for reproducible results
set.seed(123)
# Generate lengths of sample income trajectories
lengths  = sample(8:27,500,replace = T) %>% as.list()
# Use rnorm to generate income trajectories of varying lengths, as defined above
inc_traj = list() %>% .[1:500] %>% map2(lengths, ~ rnorm(.y, 1588.647, 1484.186))
# Create list which allows comparison of all trajectories with that of the first participant
pairs    = list() %>% .[1:500] %>% map2(as.list(1:500), ~ inc_traj %>% .[c(1,.y)])

# Empty list of distances to populate using for loop below
distances = list()
# Empty vector of step pattern names to populate using for loop below
name = c()
# Define loop counter
l = 0

# For each Rabiner-Juang family
for (a in 1:7) {
  # For each slope-weighting sub-type
  for (b in 1:4) {
    # For both smoothed and unsmoothed applications
    for (c in 1:2) {
      
      # Increase loop count by 1
      l = l + 1
      
      # Use try catch to treat errors
      tryCatch({
        # Calculate the distance between the first income trajectory and all other trajectories in the sample
        temp = pairs %>% map(~ dtw(.[[1]], .[[2]], keep = T, step = rabinerJuangStepPattern(a,letters[b],smoothed = {c == 1}))) %>% 
                          map(~ .$distance) %>% unlist()
        # Assign distances to distances list
        distances[[l]] = temp
      }, 
      # No additional commands for warnings
      warning=function(war) {}, 
      # No additional commands for errors
      error=function(err) {}, 
      # If code fails to run, assign NULL to distances list
      finally=function(f) {
        distances[[l]] = NULL
      })
      
      # Add name to name list
      name[l] = paste0("Rabiner-Juang:",a,",",letters[b],",smoothed=",{c == 1})
      
      # Print for loop progress
      cat("\r", paste0("Rabiner-Juang:",a,",",letters[b],",smoothed=",{c == 1},". ",l," of ",7*4*2," calculated."))
      
    }
  }
}

# Assign names to all list objects
distances = distances %>% setNames(name)

# Get names of Rabiner-Juang step patterns that worked correctly
distances %>% map(~ !is.null(.)) %>% unlist() %>% .[. == T] %>% names()
```

The output from this code indicates that step patterns from families I, V and VII work correctly, whilst those from families II, III, IV and VI produce the error.

**My questions are therefore as follows:**

**1)     Why do some of these families work, whilst others produce an error? Is this because certain families are inappropriate for this kind of data, or is my implementation wrong?**

**2)    Does anyone know of any theoretical reasons why some step-patterns might be preferred over others in this use-case?**

Many thanks in advance for your time!!!

*Citations:*

*Rabiner, L. R., & Juang, B.-H. (1993). Fundamentals of speech recognition. Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice Hall.*

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but some cases don't work due to windowing, see Figure 5 in [the package's vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtw/vignettes/dtw.pdf). Additionally, the [documentation for Rabiner-Juang's set](https://rdrr.io/rforge/dtw/man/stepPattern.html) specifically says "Not all combinations of arguments make sense", although it doesn't say why.